# lock free queue enqueue if not empty

Tags: c, atomic, lock-free, skip-lists

I have implemented a lock free queue in C using compare and swap based on http://www.boyet.com/articles/LockfreeQueue.html.

Its working great but I'm trying to integrate this queue into a lock free skip-list that i have implemented.  I'm using the skip-list as a priority queue and would like to use the lock free queue inside each node to store multiple values when there is a priority collision.  however due to the way nodes are managed in the skip list when i detect a priority collision i need to be able to add the item to the queue only if the queue is not empty.

due to the lock free nature of the queue im not sure how to actually perform this operation.

So basically how would i write an atomic enqueue_if_not_empty operation?

Comment: This code has a subtle fault.  As the document states (http://www.boyet.com/articles/ABAProblem.html) it works in C# because of garbage collection.  It will **NOT WORK** in C.

Comment: I am using a reference counting system that resolved the ABA problem on the nodes in my queue. so it is guaranteed that nodes are not freed to early.

Comment: I've never come across any ref count based solution which permits the free()ing of queue elements.  I could imagine a ref count based solution which permitted the returning of elements to a freelist, but that's it.  Are you saying you have designed a ref count based safe memory reclaimation algorithm?

Comment: i don't understand the difference between returning to a free list vs. calling free (which just returns it to a different free list).  how could it be safe for one and not another.

Comment: If memory is returned to your free list, that memory remains validly allocated for your process and any threads you have can safely dereference pointers to those elements (which happens in many lock-free algorithms).  Memory which has been free()ed is returned to the operating system and so no longer belongs to your process.  If a thread tries to dereference such a pointer, your process will crash.

Comment: Take the M&S queue as an example.  Imagine you have a queue element which is being operated on by a thread.  That thread then pauses (scheuled out).  Another thread then dequeues that element - and, rather than returning it to the freelist, actually calls free().  The first thread kicks back into life - and tries to access the next pointer of that element.  Process will then crash; invalid memory access.

Comment: It works okay when the element is in the freelist, because of the ABA counter; an element in the freelist won't ever inadvertantly be used.  But being able to *access* that element is necessary.

Comment: Have you written test for your code?  something with a bunch of threads concurrently running flat out?  you need something like that to start showing up any timing issues.

Comment: I have tested extensively. because i am using ref counting, when the first thread is swapped out it will have already inc'd the ref count so the node will not be freed until after it wakes up (and calls dec_ref).

Comment: I don't have information to go on, because I don't know how you've implemented ref counting, but my feeling is it cannot solve safe memory reclaimation and if that is the case, then there are failure cases which are not yet apparent.  Would you publish the code in this thread?  I'm curious to see what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As it was noticed, I wrote the function with quite the opposite semantics - enqueuing only into an empty queue. I fixed the name to reflect that, and decided to leave it as is just in case someone will be interested. So, this is not the right answer to the question, but do not downvote please, unless you find another reason :)

---

Below is an attempt to add `EnqueueIfEmpty()` to the queue implementation in the referenced paper. I did not verify that it works or even compiles.
The basic idea is that you insert a new node right after the **head** (and not the tail), provided that head's next is currently null (which is the necessary condition for an empty queue). I left additional checks for head being equal to tail, which possibly can be removed.

```
public bool EnqueueIfEmpty(T item) {
  // Return immediately if the queue is not empty.
  // Possibly the first condition is redundant.
  if (head!=tail || head.Next!=null)
      return false;

  SingleLinkNode<T> oldHead = null;

  // create and initialize the new node
  SingleLinkNode<T> node = new SingleLinkNode<T>();
  node.Item = item;

  // loop until we have managed to update the tail's Next link 
  // to point to our new node
  bool Succeeded = false;
  while (head==tail && !Succeeded) {

    // save the current value of the head
    oldHead = head;         

    // providing that the tail still equals to head...
    if (tail == oldHead) {

      // ...and its Next field is null...
      if (oldhead.Next == null) {

        // ...try inserting new node right after the head.
        // Do not insert at the tail, because that might succeed
        // with a non-empty queue as well.
        Succeeded = SyncMethods.CAS<SingleLinkNode<T>>(ref head.Next, null, node);
      }

      // if the head's Next field was non-null, another thread is
      // in the middle of enqueuing a new node, so the queue becomes non-empty
      else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  if (Succeeded) {
    // try and update the tail field to point to our node; don't
    // worry if we can't, another thread will update it for us on
    // the next call to Enqueue()
    SyncMethods.CAS<SingleLinkNode<T>>(ref tail, oldHead, node);
  }
  return Succeeded;
}
```

Comment: if the head.next is null and the tail==head then the queue is empty...so we would want the enqueue to fail.  i think you wrote enqueue_if_empty not enqueue_if_not_empty...unless im confused.

Comment: Great catch! My mistake - indeed, I wrote the opposite of what was desired :) I will leave it in this answer, and maybe write another one.

Comment: If head == tail and oldHead = head, won't oldHead.next always be NULL?  why the check for it?

Comment: @Blank Xavier: not it will not. Actually, the primary condition for the queue being empty is head.Next==null, because changing the reference to the next item is the first operation visible to other threads. So it's the check for head==tail that might be considered redundant; but I left it "just in case", and to some extent for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Enqueue-If-Not-Empty appears to be relatively straightforward, but with a limitation: other threads may concurrently remove all previous items from the queue, so that after insertion at the tail is done, the new item might happen to be the first in the queue. Since atomic compare-and-swap operations are done with different fields (enqueuing changes `tail.Next` while dequeuing advances `head`), stronger guarantees would require additional complexity not only in this function but at least in `Dequeue()` as well.

The following changes to the normal `Enqueue()` method are sufficient:
1) at the function start, check for `head.Next` being null, and if so, return immediately as the queue is empty.
2) add `head.Next!=null` into the loop condition in case enqueuing attempts should be stopped if the initially non-empty queue becomes empty before insertion succeeds. This does not prevent the situation I descibed above (because there is a time window between the check for emptiness and the node insertion), but reduces its chance to happen.
3) at the end of the function, only try advancing the tail if the new node was successfully enqueued (like I did in the Enqueue-If-Empty answer).